# Django - ModelChoiceField - TypeError - __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm on Django 1.2.  I'm trying to use the ModelChoiceField in a form.  Why are these failing with the above error message?  I'm at a loss :-(

```
class QueueForm(forms.Form):
    queue = forms.ModelChoiceField(query_set=Order.objects.all())
```

I also tried this:

```
class QueueForm(forms.Form):
    queue = forms.ModelChoiceField(query_set=Order.objects.all(),required=False)
```

And got:

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

It seems to be saying this is happening on the queue = .. line.  Before I even use the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the wrong variable name in the constructor, it needs to be queryset and not query_set. Try this:

```
class QueueForm(forms.Form):
queue = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Order.objects.all())
```

Comment: Wow!  I knew it had to be something obvious like that :-( I feel dumb.

Comment: Glad to help! It would be nice if the Django function parameters had more consistent variable name conventions.